# accepts_nested_attributes_for stops my sub-form rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an association between 2 models, Business and Address. where the business has a registered_address. I have done this as follows.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_one :registered_address, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => :business_registered_address_id
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :registered_address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :business
end
```

This association works fine for my purposes. When I render the form using:

```
= form_for @business do |form|
  = form.inputs :name => "Registered address" do
    = form.fields_for :registered_address do |address|
      = address.input :postcode
      = address.input :line_1
      = address.input :line_2
      = address.input :line_3
      = address.input :town
      = address.input :county
```

Nothing is displayed, just an empty fieldset.

When I comment out the accepts_nested_attributes_for line in Business model, it displays (but doesn't save) all the fields correctly.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the business_controller.rb file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write in your controller for this action (`new` as I think)

```
def new
  @business = Business.new
  @business.build_registered_address
  ...
end
```

or in your form `@business.registered_address.new`

```
= form_for @business do |form|
  = form.inputs :name => "Registered address" do
    = form.fields_for :registered_address, @business.registered_address.new do |address|
      = address.input :postcode
      = address.input :line_1
      = address.input :line_2
      = address.input :line_3
      = address.input :town
      = address.input :county
```

Comment: Ahh, I was missing the @business.build_registered_address.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

form.fields_for renders its block for each object in @business.registered_adress. If your array is empty nothing in showed.

You can write, for example on your controller:

```
@bussines.registered_address.new
```

And then the app will display all the form

Hope this helps